# EBNF notation of a requested programming language PL

Tags: ebnf

Let a programming language PL. Its variable definition part is described as follows:

At the beginning we have to start with the keyword "var". After writing this keyword we have to write the variable names(one or more) separated by commas ",". Then a colon ":" is inserted and after that we must write the variable type(say real, boolean, integer or char in my example) followed by a semicolon ";". After doing the previous steps there is the potentiality to declare into a new line new variables(variable names separrated by commas "," followed by colon ":" followed by variable type followed by a semicolon ";"), but we must not use the "var" keyword again at the beginning of the new line( the "var" keyword is written once!!!)

E.g.

```
var number_of_attendants, sum: integer;
ticket_price: real;
symbols: char;
```

I would like the EBNF of the above descripted programming language PL to understand it better. Ok, I may have read some texts about EBNF, but in my opinion an example is always something very useful.

Comment: Have you tried formulating a EBNF yourself?

Comment: Which EBNF?  There are many.  Perhaps you mean [ISO-14977](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-14977.pdf)?

Comment: I want a set of rules in order to construct the syntactic tree. E.g. <expression> ::= <term>+<factor>, where <factor> ::= "a","b" | <term> etc...

Comment: @DimitrisBouloutas, usually you don't get much help by simply dumping an assignment-like text and stating what you *want*. A better approach is to state the problem, show what you've tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: I have not done anything, but I want to do what I posted. However, I need to understand deeper what exactly it is, finding and posting the above mentioned post of mine.

Comment: Hello my friend. Did you find any kind of solution to your problem?